# Non-Standard widget size for Android

Tags: android, size, widget, standards

I have a use-case for a vertical 1x4 home screen widget on android. The supported size is 4x1 ie horizontal. Does anyone know if the vertical version can be implemented?

I realize changing screen orientation would scrunch the widget together, which I'm fine with. Even better would be if there was an equivalent to "overflow hidden" in css.

Has anyone come across a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems like the wrong answer.  at least as far as i can tell with android-7 platform and above, you can set the size however you want up to the full screen.  of course, that's not the recommended sizes, but there's nothing technically restricting you from implementing the widget you're talking about.  an issue to watch out for is that while you can supply different layouts for portrait and landscape, onUpdate won't be called on a screen rotation.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this. Sorry.

Comment: OK. I'll stop trying to put a square though a circle now. Thanks.

So I take it Htc sense vertical people widget is a custom solution that can't be related easily?